# get facebook page public info

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app that tries to get a page's public info using the facebook graph api in php.

I got an app access token using this link `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials` but when I use that to get a page's info I get a "400 bad request" response.

I connect to this: `https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_CODE}`

If I use the access token from the "Graph Explorer" app, it works but that is probably a user access token.

If I use the token that facebook generates with the oauth link above or the access token composed of "{APP_ID}|{APP_SECRET}" as they suggest in the [access tokens documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) it doesn't work.

In the [page api reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page) they say an app token should be enough to get a page's public info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it with an App Access Token (App-ID|App-Secret), it works perfectly fine like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/bladauhu?access_token=App-ID|App-Secret
```

If your page is not public, it will only work with a User Access Token (from a User who is Admin of the page). May be the reason why it does not work. Take App-ID and App-Secret from any App and make sure the App is public too ("Status & Review" tab in the App settings - "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?").

Comment: I just noticed the page was not published. I was previously published but facebook must have switched it off after a long time of inactivity or something. Thanks. I works now.

Comment: I follow the same steps which you mentioned in your answer. I tried with App-ID & App-Secret. but getting below exception
 {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "B3QrS4mPpvQ"
   }
}

Comment: make sure your token is correct and the page is not restricted by age or location