# Facebook Graph API : Fetch public information of Facebook Page - (Not Posts)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract / fetch public information of any random page. ( **Without Scrape Program** 
) I am trying to extract location, website, contact no.

[image: Find us section]

1) I tried to use graph explorer tool. but I observed that It requires **access_token. But by creating new token I can see information of my pages only ( pages which are created by me only)**

2) I tried to fetch information by using below url :

https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/feed?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET

**By using this API I am able to get only posts not public information of Page ( like About - Us Tab info as shown in attached image)**

refer from : [get facebook page public info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765973/get-facebook-page-public-info)

My Question is How can we fetch / extract specific tab's  public information lets say **"About us"**.

Comment: First of all, the combination of app id and app secret with a pipe symbol in the middle is a valid app access token. If you get that error, then please double-check that you copy&pasted those values correctly.

Comment: Secondly, using your app access token will only work for public pages that are not access-restricted in any way, and the feed endpoint will also only return posts that are not targeted to specific audiences. In those situations, you will need to use either a user access token for a user that is allowed to see the page/posts, or a page access token (which o course requires admin access to the page.)

Comment: @CBroe you mean to say , I can only access posts which are posted on the page. can't I access Page details which is visible publicly?

Comment: @CBroe : for your first comment, you were right, I was entering wrong app secret due to which I was getting such Oauth exception. Thanks. updated my question.

Comment: Of course the feed endpoint gives you the posts only, that’s what it is for. If you want to request other fields or edges from the page - then do so.

Comment: @CBroe Agreed but is there any way or api to extract information of other random page? Can we generate access_tocken for particular page and access public information ?

Comment: I already answered that in my second comment. // If you are unclear about what fields are available - then go read the docs for the `page` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get **public information** of any facebook page by using its graph api.

Process : 
Step 1 : Login to your facebook account

Step 2 : open this tool - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

[image: Graph Api tool]

Step 3 : Generate your User access token by clicking on Get Token button

[image: Get user access token]

[image: Permission Box]

Step 4 : Click on submit now it is showing your own information ( id and name)

[image: Showing your name and id as it is public information]

Step 5 : Additional if you are trying to fetch non public info you will see below error.

[image: Restricted information]

Step 6 : Now try to access public info of a page by changing "me" with any page Id like "JWMarriottPune"

[image: change url "me" from page Id like "JWMarriottPune"]

[image: find public info of page like location phone and name]

Step 7 : Now get your code from below tab

[image: Get your code tab]

[image: Get your http get request url]